Count the number of digits of a decimal number
I want to count decimal places. When you come to a low language like C++, and even most programming languages, there is nothing clear to solve the problem. Instead, a specific space is allocated to store the number, which C++ considers the actual number space, and this Not true, for example:
   double A = 10.0; // which has only two integers  
   double B = 0.10; // which has only one decimal digit    
   double C = 1.13; // which has two decimal digit and one integer  

They are all considered 8 bytes without taking into account that they differ in the number of digits.
I would like to make the computer implementation code more literal in this regard.

Floating point numbers don't really work that way. Try printing 34567891234566.789. You may see 34567891234566.7891. Try reading Is floating point math broken?

You can’t count decimal places in a floating point number. Floating point doesn’t  have decimal places. It has binary places. What exactly do you mean by ‘more literal’?

If you want exact decimal places, use a BCD encoded number.

In the case of 0.10, the actual value stored is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 so you could say it has 55 (or whatever, counting is hard) decimals too, kind of. Or better yet, don't count decimals of a double. Maybe what you need is some sort of BigDecimal implementation

"10.0" is 10.0 (exact), "0.10" is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625 (exact), and "1.13" is 1.12999999999999989341858963598497211933135986328125 (exact).  (For IEEE-754 64-bit representation.)

NB They are all 8 bytes. No ‘considered’ about it, and nothing to ‘take into account’.

"there is nothing clear to solve the problem" - What is the problem exactly?

Also see: std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10.

Decimal  numbers can only be approximated by binary floating point numbers. If you want decimal numbers, consider a library like https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html .

I want to count decimal places.  Why?  This sounds like either a very bad homework assignment given to you by a teacher, or the Y part of an XY problem.

You have a misunderstanding of how computers store floating-point numbers (and numbers in general).
Integers and Radix
The “digits” you see in a number are a consequence of how we represent a number in text. We humans typically like using numbers with a radix of ten, meaning each digit can have ten distinct values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.
Thereafter it is just a polynomial:
    1234 ⟶ 1×10³ + 2×10² + 3×10¹ + 4×10⁰
Computers usually store numbers using radix = 2. So when it prints a number for us, it converts that binary value into a decimal number representation that we humans can read and understand — because it is what we are used to.
For a simple integer, use the logarithm to find the number of digits.
Floating-point Numbers
Life becomes less simple when we are dealing with floating point values. In fact, there is a very famous paper that everyone who uses computers and floating point values should read:
What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic
The short answer is that anything after the decimal point is an approximation, and the number of “digits” you see is entirely up to you.
Easy answer #1
Now, you may wish to say: given 3.1400, that has TWO non-zero trailing digits after the decimal point (plus one digit to the left, making three non-zero non-trailing digits total).
The simplest way to find that is to convert the number to string and then count all the digits except for trailing zeros after the decimal point.
Easy Answer #2
A common trick is to use what is called Fixed-Point arithmetic. The basic idea is this:

Use integers to represent a number times some 10ᵏ, where k is a positive value > 1.

For example, if I take k as 3, then I can have an integer value 12340 to represent the fractional value 12.340. All your usual mathematical operations work on it just fine. You just need to remember to stick a decimal point in there k places to the left.
